# In GAE, when might a User not have an ID

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am building a web app with `go` and `GAE`. I would like to use Google Accounts for authentication. The `appengine/user` package contains a type, `User`. I was planning on using `ID` property of `User` as the ancestor to descendent entities in the `Datastore`. However I'm confused by the comments in this section of documentation:

```
type User struct {
    Email      string
    AuthDomain string
    Admin      bool

    // ID is the unique permanent ID of the user.
    // It is populated if the Email is associated
    // with a Google account, or empty otherwise.
    ID string

    FederatedIdentity string
    FederatedProvider string
}
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/reference#User

Under what circumstances might an email not be associated with a google account and therefore `ID` be empty?

I'm very new to `go` and `GAE` so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Thanks @3of3. So I assume that if I use the default GAE authentication option where you must have a google account the User would always have an ID. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

There are several key differences between email and id. E.g. "The app can also access a user ID that identifies the user uniquely, even if the user changes the email address for her account." Also "Every user has the same user ID for all App Engine applications."

Like [ThunderCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4130971/thundercat) said, if you use a Federated Login (OpenID was the only one supported, but is no longer), then you will not get a user id.

See [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/) for more info.